# Play/Scala - How display returned web request as html

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I make a GET request to Google and Google returns a bunch of html for a login page. When I currently try to display that request it outputs the html as straight text, rather than a nice web page.  How do I display the returned page?

Here's my function.  I have `/login` set to route to the login function.

```
def login() = Action {
  var loginUrl: String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
  loginUrl += "client_id=" + clientId
  loginUrl += "&response_type=code"
  loginUrl += "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri
  loginUrl += "&scope=" + scope
  loginUrl += "&access_type=offline"

  Logger.info("sending login request to: " + loginUrl)

  val duration = Duration(10, SECONDS)
  val future: Future[Response] = WS.url(loginUrl).get()
  val response = Await.result(future, duration)
  Logger.info("Response: " + response.toString)
  Logger.info("Status code: " + response.status.toString())

  Ok(response.body)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Await.result`, that really defeats the purpose of using an asynchronous framework like Play.  You should also avoid the use of `var`.

You want something like this:

```
def login() = Action.async {
  val loginUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" +
                s"client_id=$clientId" +
                 "&response_type=code" +
                s"&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri" +
                s"&scope=$scope" +
                 "&access_type=offline"

  Logger.info("sending login request to: " + loginUrl)

  implicit val duration = Duration(10, SECONDS)
  WS.url(loginUrl).get().map { response =>

    Logger.info("Response: " + response.toString)
    Logger.info("Status code: " + response.status.toString())

    Ok(Html(response.body))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I do `Ok(Html(response.body))` it cant find the value `Html`. I looked around for what to import but didn't find it... Should I import something for that? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Ah, found I needed play.api.templates.Html. Now it all works!

Comment: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.Html